# Character data not rendering correctly using PHP fgetcsv (character set issue)

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

**[File csv](http://invait.ru/TestCsvDump/test.csv)**

**[Page with results](http://invait.ru/TestCsvDump/TestCsvDump.php)**

Code:

```
<?php
$file_name = 'test.csv';

if (($handle_f = fopen($file_name, "r")) !== FALSE)
{

while ( ($data_f = fgetcsv($handle_f, 20000, ";"))!== FALSE) {
echo Name - '.$data_f[0].', City - '.$data_f[1].', Adress - '.$data_f[2].', Site - '.$data_f[3].'<br>';
}

fclose($handle_f);
} else {$err = 1; echo "File not open";}
?>
```

For example in result i would be get next(for example first 2 rows):

```
Name - Сибвез, City - Абакан, Adress - ул. Советская, 44, Site - www.sibvez.ru
Name - Быттехника, City - Абакан, Adress - ул. Дружбы народов, д. 52, Site - www.sibvez.ru
```

But now in results first 2 rows next:

```
Name - , City - , Adress - . Советская, 44, Site - www.sibvez.ru
Name - , City - , Adress - . Дружбы народов, д. 52, Site - http://www.bytech.ru
```

Tell me please why i cannt get correctly results?

Comment: Probably because you used the wrong charset.

Comment: @YUNOWORK charset file .csv an file .php is UTF-8 without bom. tell me please where error?

Comment: It would help if you post an example of the `CSV` file.

Comment: y, but as far as i know, .csv usually uses some windows-3410 (or whatever) charset, not UTF-8, thats why you get these encoding errors.

Comment: @Tuga see start question please. i give all links(link on csv http://invait.ru/ExPRoG/TestCsvDump/test.csv)

Comment: @learner the file you sent only has ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;....

Comment: You can't just ask for an answer as to why you're not getting the correct results - how do we know what results you are looking for? Also, that csv file looks awful

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of what should be in the csv file?

I tried the csv file opened it in notepat++ and tried all cyrillic encoding and found not much info in the csv content. So it will be helpful if you show us how it look likes in your end.

Comment: @Ryan i add exaple results in question, see please

Comment: @rccoros see link please - http://clip2net.com/s/6Beurb

Comment: @MarcAudet link on file csv was updated

Comment: I was able to read your results page correctly by adding Russian as a language to my FireFox content options.

Comment: @MarcAudet yes , now all work, thanks all. P.S.: **Leo Loki** give correct answer(need use set locale in start file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you are need set correct locale** - use `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.CP1251');`

**Full code:**

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.CP1251');
echo strtoupper('SERVER USE LOCALE ru_RU.CP1251');

$file_name = 'test.csv';

if (($handle_f = fopen($file_name, "r")) !== FALSE)
{

while ( ($data_f = fgetcsv($handle_f, 20000, ";"))!== FALSE) {
echo 'Name - '.$data_f[0].', City - '.$data_f[1].', Adress - '.$data_f[2].', Site - '.$data_f[3].'<br>';
}

fclose($handle_f);
} else {$err = 1; echo "File not open";}
```

Reference for setlocale: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: In practice, would you reset the locale back to the original value after parsing the file?

Comment: Would it be safer to use LC_CTYPE instead of LC_ALL?

Comment: @MarcAudet my practice show that if not use `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.CP1251');` in start file, data will be got not correct.  But many hostings in USA not has it locale(ru_RU.CP1251).

Comment: @MarcAudet need read information about `LC_CTYPE` becouse i all use `LC_ALL`. It single answer which i can get 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a syntax error here:

```
while ( ($data_f = fgetcsv($handle_f, 20000, ";"))!== FALSE) {
echo Name - '.$data_f[0].', City - '.$data_f[1].', Adress - '.$data_f[2].', Site -        '.$data_f[3].'<br>';
}
```

Should be:

```
while ( ($data_f = fgetcsv($handle_f, 20000, ";"))!== FALSE) {
echo 'Name - '.$data_f[0].', City - '.$data_f[1].', Adress - '.$data_f[2].', Site -        '.$data_f[3].'<br>';
}
```